# Issues with toolbar after implementing a tab layout using fragments and viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to begin by saying that my search feature is completely functional and works perfectly when it is called from my main Activity.

However I'm working on an app where I want a different activity to be opened when I select the search icon and then there should be two tabs "Quotes" or "Author".

Selecting either one should reference two fragments I created so I can either search for a particular quote or Author.

I'm manipulating a particular [sample](https://github.com/krishna1123/cheesesquare-master) I found on gitHub. The problem is whenever I select the search icon in the main activity, the Search Activity i created is referenced, however the SearchView or the settings menu is not visible, and also the fragment Tabs that should be visible are also absent, and from my toolbar i'm not able to go back to the main activity where all of these that i just mentioned are present in the toolbar.[This is how it actually looks](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ig012jkrjbutm0j/Desired%20Look.PNG?dl=0).

I followed the sample project precisely so i'm just really curious what could i be missing, or what could be the possible reasons why there is nothing visible in the toolbar even though all the menu items has been inflated and implement like the main activity?

This is the search activity i reference when action search is selected from the main activity

```
    public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if (navigationView != null) {
        setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
    }

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    if (viewPager != null) {
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
    }


    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new AuthorSearchFragment(), "Quotes");
    adapter.addFragment(new QuoteSearchFragment(), "Authors");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }
            });
}

static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

Here is my Main activity where all menus and searchView are visible in toolbar

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener  {
@Bind(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch

    displayView(0);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if(id == R.id.action_search){
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    displayView(position);
}


private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_home);
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FavoriteFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_favorite_quote);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new AddQuoteFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_add_quote);
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new CategoryFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_category);
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new PhotoEditorFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_photo_editor);
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new AllAuthorsFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_author);
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new QuoteAlarmFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_quote_alarm);
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new MyQuotesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_my_quotes);
            break;
        case 8:
            fragment = new QuotesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.nav_item_quotes);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

}

This is one of the fragments that should be Tab to search by a particular criteria

```
public class AuthorSearchFragment extends Fragment implements  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

AuthorViewAdapter authorViewAdapter;
List<AuthorAdapterModel> filteredAuthors;
List<AuthorAdapterModel> beforeFilter;
DrawableHelpers drawableHelpers = new DrawableHelpers();
List<Author> authorList;


@Bind(R.id.recyclerView)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

private DbSeeder dbSeeder;
public AuthorSearchFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dbSeeder = new DbSeeder(getActivity());
    dbSeeder.checkDatabase();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_author_search, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    initializeData();
    initializeAdapter();
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

    final List<AuthorAdapterModel> filteredAuthors = filterAuthor(beforeFilter, query);

    for (Author x : authorList) {
        beforeFilter.add(new AuthorAdapterModel(
                drawableHelpers.getDrawableBasedOnName(x.getAuthorName(), "_author", "drawable", getActivity())
                , x.getMyQuotes().size(), x.getAuthorName()));
    }

        authorViewAdapter = new AuthorViewAdapter(filteredAuthors, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(authorViewAdapter);

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    return false;
}

public  void initializeData(){
    authorList = new ArrayList<>();
    beforeFilter = new ArrayList<>();
    authorList = dbSeeder.GetAllAuthors();

    for (Author x : authorList) {
        beforeFilter.add(new AuthorAdapterModel(
                drawableHelpers.getDrawableBasedOnName(x.getAuthorName(), "_author", "drawable", getActivity())
                , x.getMyQuotes().size(), x.getAuthorName()));
    }
}

public void initializeAdapter(){
    authorViewAdapter = new AuthorViewAdapter(beforeFilter,getActivity());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(authorViewAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

private List<AuthorAdapterModel> filterAuthor(List<AuthorAdapterModel> authors, String query){
    query = query.toLowerCase();
    boolean found = false;

    final List<AuthorAdapterModel> filteredAuthors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (AuthorAdapterModel author : authors) {
        final String text = author.getAuthor().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredAuthors.add(author);
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (found == false) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "This Author was not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return filteredAuthors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue i was having earlier. I was calling the SearchActivity wrongly from within the "onOptionsItemSelected" function in the main activity class where i was using  "setContentView".

```
 if(id == R.id.action_search){
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    return true;
}
```

What i should have done was to create an intent to reference and start the SearchActivity. It now works perfectly as i initially intended.

```
if(id == R.id.action_search){

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , SearchActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```